# Algorithm for creating a sample that's as close to evenly distributed as possible?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have a large database of data with dates. There are large gaps and large chunks of data without gaps. I want to get a sample of this data such that the dates are as evenly distributed as possible (i.e. as spread out as possible).

E.g. if the dates are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 100]` and I want to sample 3 elements, the ideal sample would be `[1, 50.5, 100]` and I would take `[1, 4, 100]`.

Is this a known problem with an existing algorithm?

My attempt to formalize this problem would be: Given an array A, select a subarray B such that the following is minimized:

Σabs(B<sub>i</sub> - (min(A) + i * (max(A) - min(A)) / (len(B) - 1))

Comment: Yes you're right, changed it

Comment: As you speak of a database, do you have direct access to each value by its index, or only sequential access? Or can all values be loaded in memory making it an array-based problem?

Comment: @trincot it's array-based. I'm loading just the dates into memory and loading the rest of the data using the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to model this as an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). Construct a bipartite graph with vertex sets A and B. The edge from A_i to B_j has weight something like

```
abs(j / (|B| - 1) - (A_i - min(A) / (max(A) - min(A)))
```

where `A_0 <= A_1 <= ... <= A_{|A|-1}`.

Note that in your problem the graph is dense, so easily represented as a rectangular matrix of weights W[i,j].  No explicit vertex or edge data structures are needed.

A minimum weight matching would identify the elements of A for the sample.

There are several efficient algorithms for solving assignment problems.  Perhaps the best known is the Hungarian method. This can be implemented with O(n^3) run time. Actually I vaguely remember that in [this text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486402584) there's a version with O(n^2 log n) run time. I don't have access to it right now, so can't check.) An implementation I used in the 90's ran in a few seconds on a standard desktop machine for a problem with n = ~10k.  Should be able to do considerably better now.

You didn't give a definition of "large." If the DB is too big to process as a single assignment problem, you can probably get reasonable results by working in chunks.

Comment: @josejuan You should read the paper. This is an algorithm for processing k changes in edge weights after you already have a complete solution.